# How to access Input type="Checkbox" control inside <dx:ASPxGridView/>(Dev Express) at server side(c#)

Tags: html, checkbox, devexpress

I have a `dx:ASPxGridView` (Dev express gridview) which contains HTML checkboxes - `input type="checkbox"` control.
Problem is how can i access these HTML checkboxes at server side, so that i can check those checkboxes according to condition.

Please suggest me how can i access these HTML checkboxes on server side.

[Code image can be found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITXlC.png)

Thanks
Girish Rawat

Answer (score 0):

First, to access a HTML element on a server, you need to mark it with the *runat="server"* attribute.

To access your checkbox, handle the [ASPxGridView.HtmlDataCellPrepared](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridView_HtmlDataCellPreparedtopic) event. In the event handler, you can get your input by using the [ASPxGridView.FindRowCellTemplateControl](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridView_FindRowCellTemplateControltopic) method. You will also need to set ID for the input.

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnDataBinding="ASPxGridView1_DataBinding" OnHtmlDataCellPrepared="ASPxGridView1_HtmlDataCellPrepared" KeyFieldName="ID">
    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewDataCheckColumn VisibleIndex="0">
            <DataItemTemplate>
                <input id="check" type="checkbox" runat="server" />
            </DataItemTemplate>
        </dx:GridViewDataCheckColumn>
    </Columns>
    <Styles AdaptiveDetailButtonWidth="22"></Styles>
</dx:ASPxGridView>

protected void ASPxGridView1_HtmlDataCellPrepared(object sender, ASPxGridViewTableDataCellEventArgs e) {
    HtmlInputCheckBox check = (HtmlInputCheckBox)ASPxGridView1.FindRowCellTemplateControl(e.VisibleIndex, e.DataColumn, "check");
    check.Checked = GetValue((int)e.KeyValue);
}

public bool GetValue(int id) {
    // your logic
    return id % 2 == 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Gosha, Thanks for your reply. But its giving error on HtmlDataCellPrepared event.

Comment: @user3068630 You should add check for the particular column at this event and also check for the contol is null or not. Remember you can only access server side controls only at this event. check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211614/find-checkbox-control-in-aspxgridview) and referenced links.