# How to find ASPxCheckBox in ASPxGridView checked or not?

Tags: devexpress

I have the following gridview column:

```
<dx:GridViewDataCheckColumn FieldName="IsSelect" Caption="#" VisibleIndex="1">
    <DataItemTemplate>
        <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="chk1" runat="server">
        </dx:ASPxCheckBox>
    </DataItemTemplate>
</dx:GridViewDataCheckColumn>
```

And my server side code is:

```
ASPxCheckBox chkColorFastness = grdColorFastness.FindRowCellTemplateControl(i, grdColorFastness.Columns["IsSelect"] as GridViewDataColumn, "chk1") as ASPxCheckBox;
```

I want to find out the checkbox is checked or not.

Answer (score 1):

According to your implementation, You must get checkbox object from the 'DataItemTemplate'. If you are having problem then follow the below reference links:

[Find checkbox control in ASPxGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211614/find-checkbox-control-in-aspxgridview?rq=1)
[Find controls in the DataItem template of ASPxGridView column](http://developmentsolutionsjunction.blogspot.in/2011/11/find-controls-in-dataitemtemplate-of.html)

After getting the checkbox object you can use the [Checked](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxCheckBox_Checkedtopic.aspx) or [CheckState](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxCheckBox_CheckStatetopic.aspx) property to know that whether it is checked or not. Go through the specified documentation links there you will find more information about these properties and online demo too.

```
if(chkColorFastness != null)
  bool isChecked = chkColorFastness.Checked;
```

Hope this help..